# why flask app is not updating the browsing after reloading?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, backend

I am beginner in flask, I am facing issue in updating the template
when i run the app `flask run` for the first time it works currently, but when I update the html or the python code and then reload the page the update does not effect in the browser 
i tried different browser but still doesn't work then i have to restart the IDE and run the app again
this is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you make sure your browser's cache is not saving the .html file?

Comment: I cleared the cache still didn't work

Comment: If you are saving the file correctly, I can only tell you to try and Ctrl + Shift + R to force cache refresh.